# Correct use of ChannelGroup

Tags: netty

For learning purposes i am expanding the SecureChatServer example of the [Netty Framework](http://netty.io/) adding rooms.

in short, every room will hold up to four chatGuests. So here are my questions:

1. I am starting from the assumption that one connecting host will have its dedicated channel, ergo one host <-> one channel. Is this correct in a default situation?
2. Is it the intended purpose of the ChannelGroup interface to be used to group channels for a situation like this, i.e. several ChannelGroups holding each no more than 4 channels so to relay the message sent to a specific channelGroup just to the members of that group?
3. Making my implementation of ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter sharable will cause my ChatServer to instantiate just one ChannelHandler object that will hold the states of all the different ChannelGroups?

Please let me know if you need any specific code to answer, thanks.